# Interromper Procedimento ao Sair do Programa

Tags: delphi

Estou utilizando um código para perguntar para o usuário se ele deseja salvar as alterações antes de sair do programa (botões Sim, Não e Cancelar).

O problema é que quando o usuário clica para salvar antes de sair (botão Sim) se ele fechar o SaveDialog que foi aberto, o programa é finalizado sem salvar nada (o correto seria o programa não finalizar, porque o usuário desistiu de salvar).

Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FFileName: string;


  resourcestring
  sSaveChanges = 'Salvar alterações de %s?';


procedure TFrmMain.CheckFileSave;
var
  SaveResp: Integer;
begin
  if REdtMinhaLista.Modified = false then Exit; //se o RichEdit for modificado
  SaveResp := MessageDlg(Format(sSaveChanges, [FFileName]),
    mtConfirmation, mbYesNoCancel, 0);
  case SaveResp of
  idYes: SaveDocument; //problema: se o usuário clicar "Sim" e fechar o SaveDialog o programa fecha.
  idNo: ; //Nothing
  idCancel: Abort;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  try
    CheckFileSave;
  except
    CanClose := False;
  end;
end;
```

Procedimento para salvar documento:

```
procedure TFrmMain.SaveDocument;
begin
  if FFileName = sUntitled then
     SaveAsDocument
  else
  begin
    REdtMinhaLista.Lines.SaveToFile(FFileName);
    REdtMinhaLista.Modified := False;
    SetModified(False);
  end;
end;
```

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código da função `SaveDocument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única coisa que precisa de fazer é mudar os valores do no case deixo o exemplo:

```
case SaveResp of
  6: SaveDocument; //idYes
  7: ; //Nothing   //idNo
  2: Abort;        //idCancel
end;
```

Lista completa da correspondência dos valores:

```
mrYes      = 6
mrNo       = 7
mrOK       = 1
mrCancel   = 2
mrAbort    = 3
mrRetry    = 4
mrIgnore   = 5
mrAll      = 8
mrNoToAll  = 9
mrYesToAll = 10
```

> Pode consultar mais informações [aqui](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=messagedlg).

**EDIT1:**

Fiz um exemplo simples do uso da mensagem para criar ou não uma pasta em um dir, deixo um exemplo:

```
//Declaro VClose como variavel global para fechar ou não o projecto 
var
  Form1: TForm1;
    VClose: Boolean;
```

---

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //passo a variavel para falso para não fechar a aplicação enquanto não der permição
  VClose := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.CheckFileSave;
var SaveResp: Integer;
    sSaveChanges, FFileName: String;
begin
  sSaveChanges := 'Salvar alterações de %s?';
  FFileName := 'FileName';
  SaveResp := MessageDlg(Format(sSaveChanges, [FFileName]), mtConfirmation, mbYesNoCancel, 0);

  //usei um memo para ter a certeza que está tudo a passar no sitio correto
  if SaveResp = mrYes then
    Begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Yes pressed');
      SaveDocument; //vamos criar a pasta com falei acima
    End
  else if SaveResp = mrNo then
    Begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('No pressed');
      VClose := True;  //se clicou não gravar então passo a var a true
    End
  else if SaveResp = mrCancel then
    Begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Cancel pressed');  //não fazemos nada
    End;
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveDocument; 
var NameDir: String;
begin
  NameDir := 'C:\TestDir';   //atribui o caminho
  if ForceDirectories(NameDir) then
    Begin
      memo1.Lines.add('Folder Created');
      VClose := True;  //se criou passo a var a true
    End
  else memo1.Lines.add('New directory failed with error : '+ IntToStr(GetLastError));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CheckFileSave;

  CanClose := VClose; //só fecha de VClose for igual a true;
end;
```

Tentei detalhar o código mas alguma dúvida avise, a única coisa que precisa de fazer é alterar o código do `savedocument` para como precisar. Mas antes aconselhava a testar o código para ter a certeza de que funciona como pretende.

> O "**segredo**" para as coisas funcionarem bem está na variável `VClose`,
>   atribuindo `false` há variável ela nunca vai fechar o projecto.

Comment: @lukkicode precisa que esclareça mais alguma coisa?

Comment: Continua sem funcionar.
O problema é quando o usuário clica em "Sim" na caixa de diálogo, o SaveDialog abre e o usuário fecha esse mesmo SaveDialog. Aí o programa sai sem salvar nada.


Experimenta abrir o Ms Word digitar algo, tentar sair, clicar em sim e fechar a caixa de diálogo de salvamento. O word continua aberto.

Comment: @lukkicode consegui ajuda-lo?

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado. 
Acabei achando um demo de um componente (TRichView) que também possui um código similar ao seu, porém com o uso de funções ao invés de procedimentos.

Comment: @Tmc, eu trocaria o `CreateDir` por `ForceDirectories` :)

Comment: @JúniorMoreira boa dica, como é apenas um exemplo e não o que foi questionado na pergunta, usei o que me veio a cabeça mais rápido

Comment: @Tmc, entendido! A vantagem dele é que você não precisar testar, pois se não existe ele ja cria!